# Allow Shift + Enter to Submit Form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a simple form whose action posts to a basic PHP script. The problem I have discovered is that if someone is typing fast and accidently has the Shift key down when they hit "`Enter`" a whole slew of PHP error messages pops up. How can I allow `Shift + Enter` to work just like "`Enter`" or at least prevent all the error messages from popping up?

Currently I do not have any Javascript in use with this form. The submit button is simply `<button class="submit button" type="submit">Update</button>`

Comment: I would love to see this "*slew of PHP error messages*"

Comment: "slew" = 6 to be exact. they are all similar to: `Warning: include(includes/footer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:`

Comment: there's got to be more to this, what's the page?

Comment: worked with no issues on FireFox

Comment: whoa, it sure does! I was using Chrome to produce the error. haven't tested in other browsers - didn't think it could be browser-specific. am testing amongst other browsers now... (Edit) Error only in Chrome although Opera opens a new window instead of submitting form.

Comment: i suspect some browsers use shift+enter for something else. also it looks quite different in IE, the red is BLUE. overriding the browser 'hotkeys' is usually a bad idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30024/discussion-between-lylecrumbstorm-and-dagon)

Comment: shift-enter means "open in new window" in Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery...

```
$('input').keyup(function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
       event.stopPropagation();
  }
 });
```

Alternate to using directly with Javascript (might need to test it out)...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").onkeyup=function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're forcing me to expose more ignorance here! I reference the jQuery library (`http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js`) in order to use a prefabricated feature. If I were to use your solution how would I implement it? (shaking head in shame)

Comment: Sorry... just too used to jQuery for the comfort and ease of using it. For using jQuery, all you need to do is include this line `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the <head> section of your site. Have also edited my reply to include the javascript version of the script (might need to test it out though)

Comment: also the call should be wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... function above goes here ... });`